# using useSearchParams() for fetching dynamic data in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mongoose, next.js

Has anyone ever migrated from pages router to app router in nextjs?

I have a migration problem with dynamic data, on pages router, it retrieves dynamic data on a page using useRouter().query, whereas in app router, application it is replaced with **useSearchParams()**

How do I make the migration successful, and according to the flow in useRouter().query?

**SOURCE CODE:**

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import Link from 'next/link'
import dbConnect from '../../lib/dbConnect'
import Pet from '../../models/Pet'
/* Allows you to view pet card info and delete pet card*/
const PetPage = ({ pet }) => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('')
  const handleDelete = async () => {
    const petID = router.query.id
    try {
      await fetch(`/api/pets/${petID}`, {
        method: 'Delete',
      })
      router.push('/')
    } catch (error) {
      setMessage('Failed to delete the pet.')
    }
  }
  return (
    <div key={pet._id}>
      <div className="card" style={{ width: '1000px' }}>
        <img src={pet.image_url} />
        <h5 className="pet-name">{pet.name}</h5>
        <div className="main-content">
          <p className="pet-name">{pet.name}</p>
          <p className="owner">Owner: {pet.owner_name}</p>
          {/* Extra Pet Info: Likes and Dislikes */}
          <div className="likes info">
            <p className="label">Likes</p>
            <ul>
              {pet.likes.map((data, index) => (
                <li key={index}>{data} </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div className="dislikes info">
            <p className="label">Dislikes</p>
            <ul>
              {pet.dislikes.map((data, index) => (
                <li key={index}>{data} </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div className="btn-container">
            <Link href="/[id]/edit" as={`/${pet._id}/edit`} legacyBehavior>
              <button className="btn edit">Edit</button>
            </Link>
            <button className="btn delete" onClick={handleDelete}>
              Delete
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {message && <p>{message}</p>}
    </div>
  )
}
export async function getServerSideProps({ params }) {
  await dbConnect()
  const pet = await Pet.findById(params.id).lean()
  pet._id = pet._id.toString()
  return { props: { pet } }
}
export default PetPage
```

**Link to dynamic data page:**

```
{`/pet/${item._id}
```

Answer (score 2):

`/pet/${id}` is not a query param. It's a URL segment.

`useSearchParams` return the query like `/pet?id=123`. but for `/pet/123` you need to structure your file system to make a dynamic route `app/pet/[id]/page.tsx`

the in this page, the default export will recieve a `params` object containing `id` property:

```
export default PetPage({ params }) {
  const id = params.id;

  // ...
  await dbConnect()
  const pet = await Pet.findById(params.id).lean()
  pet._id = pet._id.toString()

  return (
    <div>{pet.name}</div>
  )
}
```